# Still getting an HTTP404 error even with "try and except" clause

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to access a url and if it gives me an HTTPError I need to wait five minutes and try again (this works for this particular website). It looks like the code doesn't recognize the except clause and it still gives me an HTTPError instantly (without waiting the 5 min).

```
import urllib2, datetime, re,os, requests
from time import sleep
import time 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError, ConnectionError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

try:
        resp = requests.get(url)


except HTTPError:
        while True:
                print "Wait."
                time.sleep(305)
            resp = requests.get(url)


except ConnectionError:
        while True:
                print "Wait."
                time.sleep(305)
        resp = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Why that `if err.code==404` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You put this `resp = requests.get(url)` in to `try/except` block, but after `except` you put the same thing again. If something throws an error and you put that after `except`, it will throw that error again.

```
while True:
    try:
        resp = requests.get(url)
    except HTTPError:
        print "Wait."
        time.sleep(305)
        continue #pass the codes after this block
    except ConnectionError:
        print "Wait."
        time.sleep(305) 
        continue #pass the codes after this block
    else:
        break
```

Basically until your url responds correctly, it will run the same thing again and again.

Comment: I removed the if statement but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Solar Can you try that with if statement again. Without `while` loop

Comment: your code still isn't delaying for 5 minutes and then trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your except blocks, you have this:

```
resp = requests.get(url)
```

This isn't protected by a try block, so it throws an error. You have to rearrange your code a little:

```
while True:
    try:
        resp = requests.get(url)

    except HTTPError:
        print "Wait."
        time.sleep(305)    

    except ConnectionError:
        print "Wait."
        time.sleep(305)

    else: break
```

It's now an infinite loop. When the connection fails, the loop just continues. When it succeeds, the loop exits.

Comment: So how you break that `while` loop after `if err.code ` statement? It's infinite too and unbreakable in your answer

Comment: @howaboutNO Fixed. I was just copying the code because I was on a stupid phone. Didn't realize that issue.